# NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionary in a TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a problem with using an `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableDictionary`.

I've created a quiz that when it stops, it should display the current score and date in a `tableview`. It should then display those values in a `tableview`. But nothing is displayed in the tableview when I load its `viewController`. The `mutableArray` is created in the `viewDidLoad:` method. Is my code correct, or am I missing something here?

```
- (IBAction)saveResult:(id)sender {

    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"DATE", nil)];// @"HH:mm zz"];

    dateNow = [NSDate date];
    NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateNow];


    // Add the quiz result to the array, reload the data in the tableview
    highscoreAndDate = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i points", score], @"kResult",
                          formattedDateString, @"kDate", nil];

    [highscore addObject:highscoreAndDate];

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

**My tableView methods:**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [highscore count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat: @"HH:mm zz"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[highscore objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"kResult"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[highscore objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"kDate"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: show me view didLoad method.

Comment: This is not a question about Xcode.

Comment: put break point at cellForRowAtIndexPath and check is it run ?? if it is not run then put your logic on viewWillAppear method:)

Comment: Have you alloc+init highscore array? check in numberofrowsinSection by NSLog(highscore.count);

Comment: show your code of viewdidload may be you load your tableview before your array is created

Comment: just check have u allocated and initialized NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0):

@Anoop Vaidya.

You got me going on the right track. I put the NSLog statement when the objects are added and it shows that the row count of my array is going up. So my code is correct.

I figured out that it was due to my connections in my XIB file (very embarrassing!). Should have spotted that my self. I had hooked up my tableview outlets to the wrong viewController and so the tableview was never populated.

Very sorry for have taken up your time and thanks to everybody who responded so quickly. Glad I got it fixed. :)